# how to show the value of alias in android database query

Tags: android, mysql

how can i view the value of alias which is value2 using custom adapter

```
int d=1000;
    int b=4;
    int c = d / b;
    cursor = db
            .select("select _id, column1/column2 as value,column1/column2*"
                    + d
                    + " as value2 from TABLE where value <"
                    + c
                    + ");
```

i tried something like this

```
   menu.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("value2")));//to get the value of alias which is "value2"
```

Comment: What columns did you get in the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the index of the field

```
 menu.setId(cursor.getString(1));
```

=0 but i think should work with

```
  menu.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("value2")));
```

like you did!

If your field is defined as `TEXT` use: `cursor.getString()`

If your field is defined as `INTEGER` use: `cursor.getInt()`

Comment: i think there should be `cursor.getString(2)`.